# comments_popup_link() - how to load different classes/images according to different comment condition?

Tags: comments, css

As the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comments_popup_link) says the syntax:

```
<?php comments_popup_link( $zero, $one, $more, $css_class, $none ); ?>
```

it's clear that we can load different texts according to different comment conditions, like "Comments Open", "1 Comment", "2+ Comments" and "Comment off", and additionally we can load CSS class to the portion.

I want to load different images from an Image-sprite with the different comment-conditions:

- When comment is open but no comment is posted - load one
- When comment[s] is/are posted - load one
- When comment is closed - load one

**What I thought**
...is to load different classes, so that I can enable different images to the `<div>` using CSS, targeting the classes.

But **HOW**?
We have only a single class to the `<div>` and a single class to the `comments_popup()`:

```
<div class="comments-link">
   <?php comments_popup_link( __( 'Post a Comment', 'your-theme' ), __( '1 Comment', 'your-theme' ), __( '% Comments', 'your-theme' ), 'comment-popup', __( 'Comment is OFF', 'your-theme' ) ) ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `get_comments_number()` to determine the number of comments, and prepare the CSS class with that information:

```
$css_class = 'zero-comments';
$number    = (int) get_comments_number( get_the_ID() );

if ( 1 === $number )
    $css_class = 'one-comment';
elseif ( 1 < $number )
    $css_class = 'multiple-comments';

comments_popup_link( 
    __( 'Post a Comment', 'your-theme' ), 
    __( '1 Comment', 'your-theme' ), 
    __( '% Comments', 'your-theme' ),
    $css_class 
);
```

Comment: Added your answer into [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comments_popup_link#Load_Different_CSS_classes_according_to_Comment-condition). Thanks again.